# How can I load an image to a UIImageView

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, swift5

I am looking to search my Firebase storage for the image named with my user's UID, and then display that image in a `UIImageView`. This is not working at the moment, and I'm not sure why. Any answers would be appreciated.

```
@IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getUserInfo()
    downloadProfilePicture()


}

func downloadProfilePicture() {
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let profilePicture = Storage.storage().reference().child("ProfilePictures").child(userID!)
profilePicture.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("An error was encountered")
    } else {
        self.picture.image = UIImage(named: userID!)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...this is embarrassing.

```
func downloadProfilePicture() {
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let profilePicture = Storage.storage().reference().child("ProfilePictures").child(userID!)
profilePicture.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("An error was encountered")
    } else {
        self.picture.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
}
```

Firebase Docs helped me out on this one [in the "Download" section of Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files). Consider my face, palmed.